# Ubuntu keeps spamming notifications on firefox

Tags: notification, browser

So i disabled notifications on the firefox website but it spams notifications. What could of caused this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have disabled notifications for all websites? Open Firefox's settings, click "Privacy & Security", scroll down to the part labeled "Notifications", and click "Settings" next to "Notifications".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be adware. It is rather common actually, I ended up fixing spammed notifications for my sister like a month ago, they were fake mcafee notifications. I would:

1. Run a scan with clamAV
2. Check the plugins and extensions installed
3. Take a look at which websites the notifications are coming from, are they notifying you about you’re Twitter feed, or hot singles in your area?

And that’s about it, let me know how it goes!

Comment: I only want to disable notifications for ̲̲̲ websites.

Comment: and when i delete them when notifications is full (sorry I'm eating a sandwich) It spams again

Comment: @DrakeKrewson What you are describing sounds like adware, and you will stop getting notifications if you find it and get rid of it.

Comment: yep I am.how do I get rid if it?

Comment: @DrakeKrewson you just follow the directions I have to you in my answer.

Comment: looks like it did it!